# Use LuaBind to call Lua functions inside a class when Lua is bound inside THAT class

Tags: c++, class, lua, luabind

Basically, I just want to be able to have a clean Lua instance made inside of my Manager class, then export the functions in the class to Lua, so that I can call functions on the already created C++ class inside of Lua.

This is the current way I am looking at solving the issue. It compiles but nothing happens in Lua.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or does anyone have any other suggestions?

**Manager.lua**

```
newObject("Object", 1234)
printAll()
```

**Manager.h**

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

extern "C"
{
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}
#include "luabind/luabind.hpp"
#include "Object.h"


class Manager
{
private :
    lua_State *L;
    std::vector<Object> obj;


public :
    Manager();
    void newObject(std::string t, int nm);
    void printAll();

};

#endif
```

**Manager.cpp**

```
#include "Manager.h"
Manager::Manager()
{
luabind::open(L);

luabind::module(L) [
    luabind::class_<Manager>("Manager")
        .def(luabind::constructor<>())
        .def("newObject", &Manager::newObject)
    ];

luaL_dofile(L, "Manager.lua");
}   

void Manager::newObject(std::string t, int nm)
{
    if(t == "Object")
    {
        Object object(nm);
        obj.push_back(object);
    }
}

void Manager::printAll()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < obj.size(); i++)
        std::cout << obj[i].getNum() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so that I can call functions on the already created C++ class inside of Lua.

If you use Luabind to create a class, and then provide members of that class, then Luabind will do exactly that. It will expose a class to Lua that has members.

You cannot call a member function in C++ without an object of that class's type. And therefore, when you expose a class and its members through Luabind, you will not be able to call member functions in Lua without an object of that class's type.

Therefore, if you have some global `Manager` object, the proper way to expose this to Lua is to expose the object itself to Lua. Use Luabind to get the global table, then put a pointer to your Manager object in it. Alternatively, you can pass the `Manager` object instance as a parameter when you execute the script.

The second method would work something like this:

```
//Load the script as a Lua chunk.
//This pushes the chunk onto the Lua stack as a function.
int errCode = luaL_loadfile(L, "Manager.lua");
//Check for errors.

//Get the function from the top of the stack as a Luabind object.
luabind::object compiledScript(luabind::from_stack(L, -1));

//Call the function through Luabind, passing the manager as the parameter.
luabind::call_function<void>(compiledScript, this);

//The function is still on the stack from the load call. Pop it.
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

Your Lua script can get an instance with Lua's varargs mechanism:

```
local manager = ...
manager:newObject("Object", 1234)
manager:printAll()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. You wouldn't happen to have a code sample, or know a site that has a good one do you?I am just trying to get my mind around the situation.

Comment: Do I need to leave the creation of the Module there?

Comment: @User947871: Yes. Luabind is not magic; it cannot parse a C++ definition and magically bind functions and such. That's what the Luabind binding code is for. All this code does is actually give Lua an instantiation of the class to _use_.

Comment: Actually, I do have one more question. Once I get it setup, how can I call a Lua function from C++ in that same script. For example, I want to have a Lua function called, keyPress(), that I want to call from inside of C++.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to fix it myself using luabind::call_function<void>(L, "keyPress");